# "invalid time series parameters specified" error in R

Tags: r

I am trying to modify the Nelson/Siegel example from the YieldCurve documentation using data from the USTYC package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/YieldCurve/YieldCurve.pdf).

The original code is:

```
library(YieldCurve)

### Nelson.Siegel function and Fed data-set ###
data(FedYieldCurve)
rate.Fed = first(FedYieldCurve,'5 month')
maturity.Fed <- c(3/12, 0.5, 1,2,3,5,7,10)
NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel( rate= rate.Fed, maturity=maturity.Fed )
y <- NSrates(NSParameters[5,], maturity.Fed)
```

My modified code is below

```
library(ustyc)
library(YieldCurve)
xlist = getYieldCurve() # 2.5 mins

yields <- xlist$df
maturities <- c(1/12, 3/12, 6/12, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30)
curve <- yields["2018-05-21",1:11]
NSParameters <- Nelson.Siegel(curve,maturities)
y <- NSrates(NSParameters[1,],maturities)
```

However, I am getting the error:

> Error in attr(x, "tsp") <- c(1, NROW(x), 1) : 
>        invalid time series parameters specified

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Solved it: 'yields' is in the wrong format. The fourth line needs to be:

```
yields <- as.xts(xlist$df)
```